# Is there a tool to plot locations within X nm of a position?

Tags: flight-planning

I'm looking for a tool to allow me to see what is within X nms or X hrs of my base airport. Is there such a thing?  I remember a small airport I flew to once had a large map with a string attached to a pin located at the airports location on the map.  There were concentric rings from the location stating 100/200/300....nm. I'm basically looking for something like that such that I could explore and look for locations that are off my normal radar of places I would typically visit.  I typically use landings.com for baseline flight planning but you need an origin and destination. It doesn't look like it allows what I'm asking for.

I'd even be happy if there was a hack for google maps etc. to do what I'm asking.

Comment: Google maps already shows a scale on it. I would think using a ruler on the screen would give you at least the same level of accuracy as the piece of string on the wall map.

Comment: http://ourairports.com/ has a "closest airports" in the airport details tab that _lists_ other airports, ordered by distance from the selected one.

Comment: Requests for specific tools are usually [off-topic here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but as it happens I was looking for something to do this a few days ago and found [this](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/calculators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least a couple of tools exist to search for airports beyond a certain distance from your departure point. You didn’t specify, so I will use mine: [KHUA](https://skyvector.com/airport/HUA/Redstone-AAF-Airport).

Using [gcmap.com](http://www.gcmap.com/), search for `near:KHUA beyond:50nm within:70nm` to get a [list of airports in the specified range](http://www.gcmap.com/search?Q=near:KHUA+beyond:50nm+within:70nm&EL=near:HUA+beyond:50nm+within:70nm&ET=Fix+location&EC=D&P=near:HUA).

To plot some of them on a map, place a few of those in a comma-separated list, e.g., `KHUA,KGAD,KBHM,KSYI,KBNA,KAYX,M22,TN50,KJFX,KMRC,KAPT,KPYP,1M4,M22`, and select the Map tool. Plot range rings with one or more lines in the **Ranges** box under **Map Controls**. I used

> 50nm@KHUA
>   70nm@KHUA

Click the Draw Map button to update your map.

The [final result](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=KHUA%2CKGAD%2CKBHM%2CKSYI%2CKBNA%2CKAYX%2CM22%2CTN50%2CKJFX%2CKMRC%2CKAPT%2CKPYP%2C1M4%2CM22&R=50nm%40KHUA%0D%0A70nm%40KHUA&PM=b%3Adisc7%2B%25i&MS=wls&DU=mi) will resemble the image below.

[image: 50 to 70nm from KHUA]

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth probably has tools to do what you are looking for.  There's a lot of flexibility in that program to create overlays.  It can sometime take some knowledge of programming to do the more complex stuff but it is a very powerful program.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a programmer by trade and it dawned on me to use the google maps api.  I imagine I could use that but I'm really am curious of airports within X nm.  Just a tool to use to itch the scratch of "where can I go for a $100 hamburger."

Comment: "probably" is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

gcmap.com allows drawing of range rings around airports. I think it's more geared up around longer range travel rather than the $100 burger, though.